# How can I include the Firebase libraries into a program in c++?

Tags: c++, firebase, libraries

I am trying to use Firebase in a Windows program in C++, but I can't find the documentation on the firebase web.
Any help?

Comment: What kind of app you wanna build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's only C++ support is in the context of its Games SDKs, so you can find it under the <kbd>Games</kbd> heading in the left navigation. The setup page is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup).

Comment: Thanks, then i am going to try making a java program.